# Different output of function run in DolphinDB Java API and GUI

Tags: dolphindb

The script is:

```
conn.login("admin","123456",false);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("'")
        .append("F:"+File.separator+"dolphinDB2"+File.separator+"DolphinDB_GUI_V1.30.13"+File.separator+"workspace"+File.separator+"test1"+File.separator+"scripts"+File.separator+"GenTradeTable.txt")
        .append("'") ;
Entity run = conn.run(sb.toString());
System.out.println("run.getString():"+run.getString());
```

and the txt file is

```
n=2000
syms=`YHOO`GE`MS`MSFT`JPM`ORCL`CISCO
timestamp=09:30:00+rand(18000, n)
sym=rand(syms, n)
qty=100*(1+rand(100,n))
price=5.0+rand(100.0, n)
t1=table(timestamp,sym,qty,price);
t1
```

The result was printed as expected in DolphinDB GUI, but Java API only returns the path to the txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For DolphinDB Java API, the parameter of `run` method is a string script, which is different from the built-in function `run`.
The corrected script is:

```
DBConnection conn = new DBConnection();
conn.connect("localhost",8848,"admin","123456");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String script = "run(\"D:/work/GenTradeTable.txt\")";
System.out.println(script);
BasicTable res = (BasicTable) conn.run(script);
System.out.println("run.getString():"+res.getString());
```